Weird reroutes for two flights flying out of KJFK
A few months ago, I was tracking some flights on Flightaware, and on July 11, 2024, I was quite surprised to see these two flights from KJFK to RKSI (Incheon, South Korea) depart toward the south, fly past New Jersey and Delaware, and then finally turn northbound while over Maryland.
KAL86:

https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/KAL86/history/20240711/0500Z/KJFK/RKSI
AAR223:

https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/AAR223/history/20240711/0445Z/KJFK/RKSI
I tried listening to LiveATC's archived audio, and it seems that AAR223 (and presumably KAL86) was rerouted so that its initial waypoint was WAVEY (I just heard the departure controller instruct AAR223 to proceed direct to WAVEY. The reroute is not reflected in the route displayed on Flightaware for some reason).
My question is: does anyone know if there was anything specific going on at JFK in the early mornings of July 11, 2024 that prevented aircraft from using the East or North departure gates? I fly this route often; we've always departed toward the north to GAYEL or east toward MERIT or GREKI. WAVEY (and then flying over New Jersey, Delaware, and Maryland) seems like a weird reroute for a flight going to East Asia, and I'd love to get some information on why this happened. This happened with two different airlines on the same day around the same time frame, so I would think this would be on the part of the ATC and not the airlines' dispatchers.
Interestingly, this was not the case with ANA159, which departed for RJTT (Ota, Japan) on that same day in the early morning. It seems to have turned north toward GAYEL while still in N90's airspace.
Bonus points if anyone manages to get the actual routing that those flights used.
ANA159:

https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/ANA159/history/20240711/0610Z/KJFK/RJTT

Those pilots just really hate Jersey and Yonkers

TL;DR: Weather.
I went to the FAA's ATC System Command Center Advisories page to see what advisories were issued on that day. The dropdown menu only goes back a couple weeks but once I was on the actual list/database page it was simple to edit the URL to reference "Thursday%2C+07-11-2024" instead of "Friday%2C+09-20-2024." On that page I found Advisory 001, NE_DELMARVA_ESCAPE, which was actually a continuation of the previous day's Advisory 113.
The escape routes were due to weather, as referenced in the 10/2200Z ops plan. Thunderstorms were affecting the normal West departure routes out of the New York area.
Per the advisory, the required routing to "escape" JFK was WAVEY EMJAY Q167 ZJAAY Q97 SAWED. Changing the FlightAware layer to the enroute sectional we can see that AAR223 didn't go all the way on that route but instead got a shortcut from before ZJAAY to either PXT VORTAC or HYTRA waypoint, and from there went direct SAW and then joined the route shown by FlightAware. KAL86 got their shortcut a little sooner, around TBONN.

It is interesting that the advisory says it's valid for aircraft with expected departure times up until 11/0230Z, but the two aircraft in question departed over two hours after that time and still got the reroute. Perhaps they had already fueled up expecting the longer route? Or perhaps the weather ended up being a problem for longer than expected? I'm not sure.
